# Xamarin dynamic grid layout

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a collection of objects that has a property like "ValueType", based on this property I invoke a DataTemplateSelector class that would return type of control to be displayed for that object.

```
<control:ControlDataTemplateSelector x:Key="personDataTemplateSelector"
                RangeTemplate="{StaticResource rangeControl}"
                EnumTemplate="{StaticResource pickControl}"
                DateTemplate="{StaticResource dateControl}"/>

<DataTemplate x:Key="rangeControl">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <control:ScreenLabel   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="{Binding Path=SortOrder, Converter={StaticResource sortOrderToColIndexConverter}}"  Text="{Binding Path=TraitDescription}" />
                        <Entry Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="{Binding Path=SortOrder, Converter={StaticResource sortOrderToColIndexConverter}}"   />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="dateControl">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <control:ScreenLabel   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="{Binding Path=SortOrder, Converter={StaticResource sortOrderToColIndexConverter}}" Text="{Binding Path=TraitDescription}" />
                        <DatePicker Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="{Binding Path=SortOrder, Converter={StaticResource sortOrderToColIndexConverter}}"></DatePicker>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="pickControl">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <control:ScreenLabel   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="{Binding Path=SortOrder, Converter={StaticResource sortOrderToColIndexConverter}}"  Text="{Binding Path=TraitDescription}" />
                        <Picker Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="{Binding Path=SortOrder, Converter={StaticResource sortOrderToColIndexConverter}}"  />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
```

I am having issue displaying these in grid with two column format, for example if there are 9 objects in the collection need to display a tabular view with 4 rows of 2 columns each and a 5th row that has one column.

With my current code, i get a zig zag kind of layout. But I need [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WlKI.png)Need some suggestions

Am looking for solution that would need to work in iOS and Droid

Answer (score 0):

I would use StackLayouts instead of Grids inside of your ViewCells.
You can do:

```
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
            <control:ScreenLabel Text="{Binding Path=TraitDescription}" />
            <Entry />
        </StackLayout>
```

Are you sure your Bindings are coming back properly? I haven't seen a comma separated Markup Extension setting on attribute.

Comment: If i use stack layout, how can i position 2 columns in one row

Comment: Add this to your StackLayout: Orientation="Horizontal"

Answer (score -1):

Any one looking for answer, we resolved it by using FLowlist view control. It provides options to have side-by-side view

Comment: Please explain solution in detail so that others will understand more easily